# Reset all values for a column except for one

Tags: mysql

This is my query which returns me the count of the `gtin` from table `gtin` in table `artikel`.

```
 SELECT   g.gtin,
     Count(a.gtin)
 FROM     artikel a
 JOIN     gtin g
     where    a.gtin IN (g.gtin)
 GROUP BY a.gtin
 HAVING   count(a.gtin) > 1
```

Now I want to reset all gtins in table `artikel` except for one. Which one does not matter. In the end each `gtin` from table `gtin` should only be used once in table `artikel` in column `gtin`.

Comment: I am unclear what table gtin has to do with anything. You could improve your question by adding sample data and expected outcome to your question as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you want to make sure that you don't have duplicate values of gtin in table artikel, and that this is unrelated to references to table gtin.

If you are using MySQL 8.0, this should be easily doable using a window function. Something like

```
update artikel set gtin = null
where row_number() over (partition by gtin) > 1
```

Haven't tested it, so there may be syntax errors.

*Edit:* If your MySQL version is lower, you can select a row from each group to keep its value by utilizing some distinguishing attribute, like `artikel_id`:

```
update artikel as a
join ( select gtin, min(artikel_id) as chosen_id
       from artikel group by gtin ) as b
    on b.gtin = a.gtin and a.artikel_id <> b.chosen_id
set a.gtin = null;
```

Comment: Its below MySQL 8 ... how would I do that in lower versions?